# Fill NSMutableDictionary with for loop and then it show me last value loaded

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

Hello I had tried to fill a NSMutableDictionary with two NSMutableArray data using a for loop, when the loop finished, the NSMutableDictionary only show me the last value loaded, whats wrong? follow the code

```
 -(void)calculateDistance
{
    self.distanceArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];



    for (int i=0; i<[self.nombre count]; i++) {


       CLLocation *shopPosition=[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[[self.latitud objectAtIndex:i] floatValue]longitude:[[self.longitud objectAtIndex:i]floatValue]];
        self.userPosition=[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:self.currentLat longitude:self.currentLong];

        self.distance=[shopPosition distanceFromLocation:self.userPosition];

       [self.distanceArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.distance]];

        [self.dict setObject:[self.distanceArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"distance"];
        [self.dict setObject:[self.nombre objectAtIndex:i]  forKey:@"nombre"];


   }

    NSLog(@" DICT %@",self.dict);
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: "Code dump", error in logic, no future use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always set the new Values to the same keys:

```
[self.dict setObject:[self.distanceArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"distance"];
[self.dict setObject:[self.nombre objectAtIndex:i]  forKey:@"nombre"];
```

you should instead use a NSMutableArray and add a new NSDictionary every loop cycle.

```
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"distance" : self.distanceArray[i],
                           @"nombre"   : self.nombre[i]
   };

    [self.newMutArray addObject: dict];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.dict setObject:[self.distanceArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"distance"];
[self.dict setObject:[self.nombre objectAtIndex:i]  forKey:@"nombre"];
```

These two lines are your problem.  Each time you get a new `nombre` or a new `distanceArray` you are saving it to the same key in your `NSDictionary`.

So in the end your `NSDictionary` will only have two keys, "distance" and "nombre."

What you may need to do is create an `NSMutableArray` of `NSDictionary` objects, otherwise you will have to start making multiple keys for each object in the dictionary, something like keys:"nombre1","nombre2", etc.

Try making an `NSMutableArray` with `i` `NSDictionary` objects in it.  Like this:

```
[array addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[self.distanceArray objectAtIndex:i],@"distance",[self.nombre objectAtIndex:i],@"nombre"]];
```

Then your final `array` object will have `i` `NSDictionary` objects with each containing a nombre and a distance key.

To access the nombre and distance at index `n` you would use:

```
nombre = [[array objectAtIndex:n] objectForKey:@"nombre"];
distance = [[array objectAtIndex:n] objectForKey:@"distance"];
```